# SQL query to calculate sum value in SQL using 2 tables without using a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, time-series, data-science

I have 2 tables in my database which have time series data. **table 1** has the following schema

[image]

using **SQL** I'm creating a **3rd table** using values from 1st and 2nd table. the 3rd table will have 3 columns

> key . date_b, sum

. The row count in 3rd table should be same as in 2nd table and **sum column** for **each key** will be calculated using the logic, when a_date>b_date sum the count value, otherwise keep it 0.

[image]

> There are 3 dates greater than 1st feb in table 1 so the sum is **9**.
> while 2 dates greater than 2nd feb in table 1 so sum is 7 and so on.

in excel i used sumifs and was able to calculate it successfully but in SQL when i'm not able to do it, if i use joins multiple records are created since keys are duplicate. what will be the sql query for creating the table 3?

Sample query that I have used:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN "date_a"> "date_b" 
    THEN SUM("count")OVER(PARTITION BY "key_b","date_b" ) 
    ELSE 0 END AS "sum"
from
(
SELECT *
  FROM table 1
) A
right JOIN
(
     SELECT * 
     FROM table_b
     
 ) B
ON A."key" = B."key")
C
```

Comment: Use `SUM()` and `GROUP BY` to combine the records with the same key after joining.

Comment: provide text instead of picture

Comment: @Barmar i have added the sample query that i have used. when i use the join multiple records are created. when i use group by on table1, i lose data since i need all the dates from table_1 to calculate the logic for sum.

Comment: Try to prevent using [MySQL reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K) as column name. Especially the ones marked with `(R)` in the documentation.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use double quotes for quoting column names by default.

Comment: The data analysis tool i'm using requires it. please ignore that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `OUTER JOIN` with condition aggregate with `group by`

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t2.`Key`,
      t2.b_date,
      SUM(CASE WHEN t1.a_date >  t2.b_date THEN t1.`count` ELSE 0 END) 'sum'
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 
ON t2.`Key` = t1.`Key` 
GROUP BY t2.`Key`,
      t2.b_date;
```

| Key | b_date | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 | 9 |
| 1 | 2022-02-02 | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-02-03 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-02-04 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-05 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-06 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-07 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-08 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-09 | 0 |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-02-09 | 0 |
| 4 | 2022-02-09 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3gYkCkjcMHH6L24zHcftAY/1)

Comment: I cannot use join on date columns, both are different date columns for different purpose, it's just that sum logic is dependent on them.

Comment: @anmolhans I had edit my answer, you just need to `OUTER JOIN` with `key` column